# Adding Alertmanager expression queries while alerting

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, promql

My intention is to add the query expressions to be displayed in descriptions or summary when alertmanager is alerting through alerting mediums.
Is it possible something like this below?

```
- alert: OutOfDiskSpace
expr: node_filesystem_free_bytes / node_filesystem_size_bytes * 100 < 10
for: 1m
labels:
  severity: Critical
annotations:
  description: "Disk is almost full. The expr query  is {{ $labels.expr }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `$value` which will display the value evaluated by the expression. For example consider the following rule

```yaml
      - alert: service_down
        expr: (probe_http_status_code - 0) != 200
        for: 1m
        labels:
          severity: 3
          threshold: danger
        annotations:
          summary: "HTTP : {{ $value }} for URL *{{ $labels.instance }}*."
          description: "*{{ $labels.instance }}* of job *{{ $labels.job }}* is down"
```

In the summary, you will get the status code of the API which is down.

In your case the following should work

```yaml
- alert: OutOfDiskSpace
expr: node_filesystem_free_bytes / node_filesystem_size_bytes * 100 < 10
for: 1m
labels:
  severity: Critical
annotations:
  description: "Disk is almost full. The expr query  is $value"
```

Comment: i'm not looking for value of the expression. I'm looking a way to print the whole expression query

Comment: @td4u Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, it is possible.

Prometheus templating language is based on the [Go templating](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) system.

You can use this to your advantage to put Prometheus queries results in your annotations templates. For example, in an `alert.rules.yml` file you could use the following on the `annotations.summary` field:

```yaml
      - 
        alert: TestAlert
        expr: go_info == 1
        for: 5s
        labels:
          severity: warning
        annotations:
          summary: "go_info value: {{ printf `go_info{instance=\"%s\"}` $labels.instance | query | first | value }}"
          description: "value: {{ $value }}"
```

On alert this will execute a promQL query for the `go_info` in this case in the format `metric{instance=[alerted instance]}`, which returns a tuple, that you can filter to the value using the processing pipes as shown above.

Source: [Prometheus Documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/template_examples/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are explicitly asking for displaying the expression `expr` in the alertmanager notifications, e.g. via slack, I can present you the following workaround. I will use the notions of the [Alertmanager Documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/notifications/)

The Data handed over to the notification templates by Alertmanager contains for every group the array `Alerts` consisting a list of all `Alert` object in this group. Since I grouped by `alertname` and my alertnames (works also if you have proper inhibition rules based on the alertname) are unique all `Alert` objects in this group will have the same `GeneratorURL`, which contains `expr` but parsed into a URL string. Since I did not found an inverse function of `urlquery` (see [Go templating default functions](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Functions)) I used following selfmade partial inverse function as templating:

```
{{ (index .Alerts 0).GeneratorURL | reReplaceAll ".*expr=" "" | reReplaceAll "&g0.*" "" | reReplaceAll "%7B" "{" | reReplaceAll "%3D" "=" | reReplaceAll "%3E" ">" | reReplaceAll "%3C" "<" | reReplaceAll "%22" "\"" | reReplaceAll "%2C" "," | reReplaceAll "%21" "!" | reReplaceAll "%7D" "}" | reReplaceAll "\\+" " " | reReplaceAll "%2A" "*" | reReplaceAll "%2F" "/" | reReplaceAll "%28" "(" | reReplaceAll "%29" ")" | reReplaceAll "%5E" "^" | reReplaceAll "%5B" "[" | reReplaceAll "%5D" "]" }}
```

This will print out the expression. If you use additional symbols (which would be converted by `urlquery`) in your expressions you may have to add some replacement steps.